# Is there a way to perform a silent installation of Magento through a bash code?

Tags: install-script, automation

Is there a way to perform a silent installation of Magento through a bash code?
This is what I have in my bash:

```
...
...
PRJ_MAGENTO_PUBK=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PRJ_MAGENTO_PRVK=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
...
...
MAGENTO_SAMPLEDATA='' 
if [ "$WITHSAMPLEDATA" -eq "1" ];
       then
            MAGENTO_SAMPLEDATA='--use-sample-data' 
fi
...

cd ~/vhosts/$PRJ_MAGENTO
    php -f ./bin/magento setup:install \
    --base-url=$BASE_URL \
    --use-secure=0 \
    --db-host=127.0.0.1 \
    --db-name=$DB_MAGENTO \
    --db-user=$DB_USER \
    --db-password=$DB_USER_PASSWORD \
    --admin-firstname=$MAGENTO_USER_FISTNAME \
    --admin-lastname=$MAGENTO_USER_LASTNAME \
    --admin-email=$MAGENTO_USER_EMAIL \
    --admin-user=$MAGENTO_USER \
    --admin-password=$MAGENTO_USER_PASSWORD \
    --language=en_US \
    --currency=USD \
    --timezone=America/Chicago \
    --use-rewrites=1 \
    --backend-frontname=admin \
    $MAGENTO_SAMPLEDATA
```

> Is there a way to pass `$PRJ_MAGENTO_PUBK` and `$PRJ_MAGENTO_PRVK` to fill the follow question?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

create an **`auth.json`** file inside your Magento installation directory and put this inside:

```
{
   "http-basic": {
      "repo.magento.com": {
         "username": "<public-key>",
         "password": "<private-key>"
      }
   }
}
```